# Error compiling irrlicht android using ndk in Mac

Tags: android, macos, irrlicht, ndk

I'm new to irrlicht and I have started with irrlicht android port. I have made the following changes to android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -I./../include/ -I./include/ -I/documents/karthik/android/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/documents/karthik/android/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so -ldl -llog -L/documents/karthik/android/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so
```

I have tried compiling irrlicht android using ndk-build in terminal.It showed the following errors at first:

```
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(const c8*, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(wchar_t const*, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
 error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(const c8*, const c8*, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
In static member function 'static void irr::os::Printer::log(const c8*, const path&, irr::ELOG_LEVEL)':
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/irrlicht/os.o] Error 1
```

and then I googled that and made changes in os.cpp file as follows:

Changed the code,

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "log", message);
```

to

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "log","%s", message);
```

This change solved that issue, and then I got another error:

```
In file included from jni/importgl.cpp:55:0:
jni/importgl.h:37:22: fatal error: GLES/egl.h: No such file or directory
```

Again I changed `GLES/egl.h` to `EGL/egl.h` and solved that issue, got:

```
fatal error: irrlicht.h: No such file or directory
```

I even solved this , atlast I'm here with this error:

```
error: 'EglDisplay' was not declared in this scope
error: 'EglSurface' was not declared in this scope
error: 'EglWindow' was not declared in this scope
error: 'EglContext' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for the issue, There is no need to edit `Android.mk` file while compiling `irrlichtandroid`. In `project/default.propeties` , I have changed:

```
target=android-4
```

to

```
target=android-18
```

And when:

```
In file included from jni/importgl.cpp:55:0:
jni/importgl.h:37:22: fatal error: GLES/egl.h: No such file or directory
```

this error occurred I did a mistake by changing `GLES/egl.h` to `EGL/egl.h` but that is not the solution for the issue. In `include/IrrCompileConfig.h` I have commented out:

```
//#define _IRR_COMPILE_WITH_OGLES1_
```

since I need only OpenGL ES 2. This solved the issue , `irrlichtandroid` compiled successfully using `ndk-build` , `libirrlicht.so` file generated in my project `libs` directory.